# Breadth-First Search for terrorist network analysis

Tags: python, networking, breadth-first-search

I am currently working with BFS to help analysts and investigators explore terrorist or criminal networks for a university paper (using Python). The main subject of my program is not oriented toward coding, so it is brand new for me.
I am actively looking for someone to help / guide me in the development of my code for such problem.
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Advised to create some sample applications first, before helping others.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you reading the fifth chapter "Graph Traversal" of the book titled "The algorithm design manual" by Steven S. Skienna where graph traversal is explained thoroughly that is with examples and exercises.

Moreover if you want some intuition for describing what BFS, here is a brief explanation:

BFS is an order for traversing a graph where we prioritize exploring the graph breathly instead of deeply. Suppose we had a tree like this:

```
(N)
 |   \
(A)   (B)
 | \   |  \
(C)(D)(E) (F)
```

if we set N as the node where our BFS search starts then the order of traversal will be:

```
(1)
 |   \
(2)   (3)
 | \   |  \
(4)(5)(6) (7)
```

This is because the algorithm maintains a FIFO (First-In-First-Out) queue of the nodes that have to be explored and keeps adding the neighbours of the actual node being explored until there are no nodes left to explore.

To illustrate things a bit lets describe BFS over this simple example. We will have a queue `Q` and a list of explored nodes `explored` in each step of the algorithm. First the queue `Q` is filled up with the starting node that is `Q = [N]` and there is nothing in the list of `explored = []`. We append the neighbours of N to the queue and mark N as explored so in the second step of the algorithm we would have `Q = [A, B]` and `explored = [N]`. Now is turn for the first of the elements of Q that is A so we append unexplored neighbours to Q and mark it as explored that is `Q = [B, C, D]` and `explored = [N, A]`. In the third we will append the unexplored neighbours of B to `Q` and mark `B` as explored that is `Q = [C, D, E, F]` and `explored = [N, A, B]`. This goes on until `Q` is empty